# symlink and mounting ftp host on another machine

Tags: vsftpd, curlftpfs

So I have machine 1 that has vsftpd installed and machine 2 that needs to mount distant ftp folder.
However machine 2 also needs to access symlink, which is what fails.
No chroot as only lan access is allowed, so no worries about security issue from internet.

**On machine 1**:

- ftp directory is: /home/ftpu/
- symlink made: ln -s /mnt/share_hdd /home/ftpu/share_hdd/

**On machine 2 (same network)**:

If I connect to the ftp using a filezilla or whatever, this works flawlessly, I can access to share_hdd folder and see its content, no worries.

However, I used curlftpfs to:

- mount machine1.local/share_hdd /mnt

Now when I browse /mnt I can **see** share_hdd folder. And if I cd inside I sort of enter a loop of folder containing another share_hdd folder containing another share_hdd folder etc etc.
In the end I'm in an endless tunnel such as /mnt/share_hdd/share_hdd/share_hdd/ etc.

What did I do wrong ?

(Oh and in case you're wondering why the hassle and not go through samba share its because machine 2 is debian chroot from a spare android phone running linux deploy on which the kernel doesn't support cifs and I do not have the skills to build a custom kernel with cifs support)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was silly of me, 2 things I miss.

I did use mount --bind BUT:

1. I forgot to put a / at the end of machine1.local/share_hdd/
2. I had to remount /mnt on machine 2 as I did the mount --bind option after mounting machine 2 which was obviously the wrong order of doing things